# Removing strings from lines part of file in bash

Tags: string, bash, sed

I need to remove/be rid of string as follow par of one file:

Here is my line:

```
2014-08-05T13:16:29+01:00 (INFO:3824.87075728): [27219] [ <emailaddress@domain.com>] A message from <emailaddress@domain.com> source]
```

As a result, I am trying to get like:

```
2014-08-05T13:16:29+01:00 (INFO:3824.87075728): [27219] source
```

In fact its to rid of the email addresses.

Thank you all for all your suggestions.

AL

I have tried to following using sed:

sed -e 's/<.* from//g'

```
2014-08-05T13:16:29+01:00 (INFO:3824.104725392): [27219] [  <emailaddress@domain.com> source
```

As now, I am trying to figure how could I remove from [ until source.

Thank you.

Comment: use `s` command of `sed`. The pattern depends on exact content you wish to remove, but as the first step you may wish to remove email-s. The basic command is sed -e "s/${EMAIL_PATTERN}//g". The exact value of ${EMAIL_PATTERN} depends on your accuracy, the official pattern is [here](http://regularexpressionsrightnow.com/items/regular-expressions/Official_W3C_email_regular_expression__RFC2822/) It's a bit lengthy :)

Comment: But the source was present within the `]` bracket. If you want to get rid off email address then why the string `A message from` is removed?

Comment: Ah, that's not a problem. Just escape all "bad symbols". For example `sed -e 's,\(\[\|\]\),,g;'` removes all brackets from the string.

Answer (score 1):

The below awk command would print the first three columns and the last column with `]` symbol removed.

```
$ echo '2014-08-05T13:16:29+01:00 (INFO:3824.87075728): [27219] [ <emailaddress@domain.com>] A message from <emailaddress@domain.com> source]' | awk '{gsub(/]/,"",$NF); print $1,$2,$3,$NF}'
2014-08-05T13:16:29+01:00 (INFO:3824.87075728): [27219] source
```

**OR**

```
$ echo '2014-08-05T13:16:29+01:00 (INFO:3824.87075728): [27219] [ <emailaddress@domain.com>] A message from <emailaddress@domain.com> source]' | sed 's/\[ .*\(source\).*$/\1/g'
2014-08-05T13:16:29+01:00 (INFO:3824.87075728): [27219] source
```

Comment: Hi thanks, ideally I was willing to use sed; as sometime the initial line might vary.

Comment: please answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156491/removing-strings-from-lines-part-of-file-in-bash/25156872?noredirect=1#comment39163637_25156491) so that we could understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The pb, is that sometime after source, line might vary so using awk would avoid to see what is included.